# ESTA Guidance needed

Tags: usa, esta, mexico, belize

I am planning on travelling to the US and Mexico on an ESTA from September, which permits me 90 days in total in both countries. However in order to be eligible for an ESTA I need to also have proof of an outbound flight.

I am planning on continuing my travels on to Belize after I finish in Mexico, and from there I would like to keep on travelling down Central America into South America. With this in mind, I have not bought a flight directly back to the UK - only UK to US, US to Mexico and Mexico to Belize.

My question is (and what I am concerned about)is whether I will still be eligible for an ESTA if my outbound flight goes to Belize instead of directly home?